# Scraping from Aria Table Column Using Rvest

Tags: r, screen-scraping, rvest

Small question, I dont think it's a replicate based on googling.

I'm trying to scrape data off a set of tables, e.g. the "NAME" http://www.votewatch.eu/en/term8-thailand-notably-the-case-of-andy-hall-joint-motion-for-resolution-paragraph-11-amendment-1.html

I'm trying to use

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
url <- "http://www.votewatch.eu/en/term8-thailand-notably-the-case-of-andy-hall-joint-motion-for-resolution-paragraph-11-amendment-1.html"
read <- read_html(url)
nodes <- read %>% html_nodes("td.sorting_1 > a") #based on copy/paste CSS selector
```

but get a node of length 0 from which I can't extract anything. I also tried using selector gadget but still couldnt get anything off of the table.

Any thoughts? thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It's because the page requires login...

[image]

you would need to authenticate first... look at [Rselenium](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/RSelenium.pdf) This is going to be much harder to scrape.

Comment: Having logged in on the browser I can (for instance) still scrape from the table above it, e.g. for the date:

`url <- "http://www.votewatch.eu/en/term8-2026-un-climate-change-conference-in-marrakesh-morocco-cop22-motion-for-resolution-vote-resolution.html"

read <- read_html(url)

nodes <- read %>% html_nodes("body > div.normal_page > div.content_all_page > div.container.content > div > div.width_60_percent.vote_facts.floatleft > div > div.vote_all_info > div:nth-child(5)")` 

As for selenium, all I have is an old work laptop at the moment, so can't give it the privileges

Comment: Admin privileges are not required for `RSelenium` and in my experience it is not resource intensive. [This tutorial](http://zevross.com/blog/2015/05/19/scrape-website-data-with-the-new-r-package-rvest/) provides nice introduction to `rvest` and `RSelenium`